# highcharts dynamic background color issue

Tags: highcharts, ionic3

I have two themes (light, dark) in my application. I'm trying to give different colors to my chart background and labels depending upon the theme of the chart. how can I change dynamically. this is my code so far:

```
chart: {
   type: 'area',
   backgroundColor: '#FBFAFA', 
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `chart.update()` method and pass a new background color there:

**Code:**

```
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    backgroundColor: '#efefef'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      pointStart: 2010
    }
  },
  series: [{
    data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
  }]
});


setTimeout(function() {
  chart.update({
    chart: {
      backgroundColor: '#c5c5c5'
    }
  });
}, 3000);
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/163fw2o7/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart

Comment: I have two builds dark theme build and light theme build. so i don't know which build gonna execute and depending on that we have to give color. what i'm looking for is how can i use scss variables inside charts. so that what ever the build corresponding color will come from scss variables.

Comment: Perhaps it will help you: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WPEZPX. You can use scss to style the chart, but if you want to change colors dynamically you have to make it with js.